# How can I compare two lists and mark faulty elements without taking items' index into account to identify breaks of order

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, namely *ordered_list* and *unordered_list*:

*ordered_list* contains items sorted in a particular order for Spanish, and this order **must not** be modified in this list:

```
ordered_list = ['a', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'ábaco', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'ábax', 'aceite', 'aceite', 'ancianos', 'ár', 'arquitrabe', 'arquitrabe']
```

*unordered_list* contains exactly the same items as in ordered_list but in a different order:

```
unordered_list = ['a', 'ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'abadía', 'ábaco', 'ábax', 'arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

Both lists have the following characteristics:

- *ordered_list* and *unordered_list* always have the same length.
- the first item in both *ordered_list* and *unordered_list* will always be the same.
- we can find dupes in both lists, but they are fine and **they should not be removed** from any list.

What I need to do is getting a third list, namely *result_list*, where the symbol **$** is added to the items in *unordered_list* that are breaking the order in *ordered_list*. The desired list would be this one:

```
result_list = ['a', '$ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', '$ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', '$aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', '$abadía', 'ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

I somehow need to compare both lists (*ordered_list* and *unordered_list*) and identify the words that are breaking that order. However, I cannot do it in an index-wise way because the item occupying a determine index may differ in both lists whilst the order is maintained and so be correct and not need to be marked. I need a code that identifies the words in both lists and takes their order into account, **spotting only those** from *unordered_list* that breach the order in *ordered_list*, and so marking them with $. The *result_list* should have the same order as *unordered_list* with the items breaking the order in *ordered_list* marked with $.

For example, in *unordered_list*, the first occurrence of the word 'abadía' is breaking the order, as there should be nothing between 'abacial' and 'ábaco' as in *ordered_list*, so this item should be marked with $. However, if we look at the second occurrence of 'abadía' in *unordered_list*, which comes after 'abadí', it is correct as it is maintaining the order after 'abadí' as in *ordered_list*.

These lists are just one example, and I have many more lists containing different words but where the procedure should be the same. Hence, I would need a code that **works for the problem as such but which does not stick to these two lists in particular**.

I have tried some code but it is not working:

```
def get_correct_order_with_marker(ordered_list , unordered_list , marker="$"):
    # Create a dictionary to map each word to its position in the correct order
    order_dict = {word: index for index, word in enumerate(ordered_list )}

    # Sort the second list based on the order in the dictionary
    sorted_unordered_list = sorted(unordered_list, key=lambda x: order_dict[x])

    # Mark items that have been moved with the distinctive symbol
    marked_unordered_list = [f"{marker}{word}" if word != sorted_unordered_list[idx] else word for idx, word in enumerate(unordered_list)]

    return marked_unordered_list

# Example usage
ordered_list  = ['a', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'ábaco', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'ábax', 'aceite', 'aceite', 'ancianos', 'ár', 'arquitrabe', 'arquitrabe']

unordered_list = ['a', 'ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', 'ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', 'aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', 'abadía', 'ábaco', 'ábax', 'arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']

result_list  = get_correct_order_with_marker(ordered_list , unordered_list)
print(result_list )
```

and all words except the first and the last ones are incorrectly being marked with $:

```
['a', '$ancianos', '$aba', '$abaá', '$ababillarse', '$ababol', '$ár', '$abacá', '$abacal', '$abacalero', '$abacería', '$aceite', '$abacero', '$abacial', '$abadía', '$ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', '$abacora', '$abacorar', '$abad', '$abad', '$abada', '$abadejo', '$abadengo', '$abadernar', '$abadesa', '$abadí', '$abadía', '$abadiado', '$abadiato', '$abajadero', '$abajamiento', '$aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

I do not really know what the problem how I can implement my code to work as expected and get the appropriate result_list with only breaking words marked with $, like this:

```
['a', '$ancianos', 'aba', 'abaá', 'ababillarse', 'ababol', '$ár', 'abacá', 'abacal', 'abacalero', 'abacería', '$aceite', 'abacero', 'abacial', '$abadía', 'ábaco', '$ábax', '$arquitrabe', 'abacora', 'abacorar', 'abad', 'abad', 'abada', 'abadejo', 'abadengo', 'abadernar', 'abadesa', 'abadí', 'abadía', 'abadiado', 'abadiato', 'abajadero', 'abajamiento', 'aceite', 'arquitrabe']
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

This can be easy with a recursion:

```py
def get_correct_order_with_marker(ordered_list , unordered_list , marker="$"):
    if len(ordered_list) == 0:
        return []
    elif ordered_list[0] == unordered_list[0]:
        return [ordered_list[0]] + get_correct_order_with_marker(ordered_list[1:], unordered_list[1:])
    else:
        ordered_list.remove(unordered_list[0])
        return [marker + unordered_list[0]] + get_correct_order_with_marker(ordered_list, unordered_list[1:])
```

- The first case is the base case of the recursion, receiving the empty list and returning the empty list
- The second case is when the unsorted current element is well placed, in this case, you should return this element without the marker and call recursively for the method skipping the first element of each list
- The third case is when the first element of each list are different, in this case, you should return the first element of the unordered list (with the marker) and then call the method but you should remove the first occurrence of the word from the ordered list and the first element of the unsorted list

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response. It perfectly works for these lists in particular. However, when I change the list, it seems not to be working for some reason... I do not know where the problem can be :(

Comment: can you please give me a non-working example?